# Which is the virtio configuration functionally equivalent to the QEMU network default?

Tags: networking, virtualization, qemu

When I start QEMU [2.7, commandline] without any NIC/network parameters, the guest has regular access to internet (it also receives an IP automatically), automatically the network connection I have on the host (wifi).

Which parameters should I use in order to have the same network functionality, with the only difference being using a virtio NIC?
The guest O/S already has the drivers installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, actually:

```
-net nic,model=virtio -net user
```